# focusout on a input form and div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a dropdown suggestion box.
In that case I wish to hide the box whenever the input field AND dropdown box is no longer in focus.

**This is my HTML code:**

```
<input type="text" id="user_address">
<div id="user_address_sg">SUGGESTION</div>

<div id="another element">Pressing another element on the page should hide the suggestion box</div>
```

**I have tried the following:**

```
$('[id=user_address][id=user_address_sg]').focusout(function (){
    $('#user_address_sg').hide();
});
```

How come the `user_address_sg` doesn't hide whenever I select another input field or other elements on the page?

**Images (1st: When I write a name, 2nd: When I select another form while suggestions appear)**

**First image: suggestion box should be displayed and clickable**

[image: Before selecting a input]

**Second image: When doing this the suggestion box should disappear**

[image: After selecting another input]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED:** CSS alternative:

```js
function suggest(key) {
document.getElementById('user_address').value = document.getElementById(key).innerHTML;  
 }
```

```css
#user_address_sg {
  vertical-align: top;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: none;
  color:black;  
}

#user_address_sg:focus, #user_address_sg:active {
  display: inline-block;
  color:black;
}

#user_address:focus ~ #user_address_sg {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="user_address">
<a href=# id="user_address_sg">
<span id=a1 onClick="suggest('a1')">SUGGESTION 1</span><br>
<span id=a2 onClick="suggest('a2')">SUGGESTION 2</span><br>
<span id=a3 onClick="suggest('a3')">SUGGESTION 3</span><br>
<span id=a4 onClick="suggest('a4')">SUGGESTION 4</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Suggestions gets hidden when pressing it. Its supposed to stay there until I select another element besides the input or the div.

Comment: Are the suggestions supposed to be links?

Comment: No, simply onclick elements that insert into the form.

Comment: It works, but how can I override this with jQuery and hide `#user_address_sg` whenever the input field is empty? or CSS for that matter.

Comment: ps: notice that its regular javascript, not jquery.

Answer (score -1):

You may need `blur` and separate the selectors with commas, because one single element with two different ids doesn't exist, but two different elements with different ids yes. So separate them:

```
$('[id=user_address],[id=user_address_sg]').blur(function (){
    $('#user_address_sg').hide();
});
```

Better with `on()` method

```
$('[id=user_address],[id=user_address_sg]').on('blur', function (){
    $('#user_address_sg').hide();
});
```

`blur` event will fire when a focused element loses the focus. So I think that's what you need.

Comment: Doesn't work. Whenever I click another input field on the page, it doesn't hide....

Comment: @Marcos The problem is there with the selector. Use this `$('[id=user_address]')`

Comment: I add a comma to separate the selectors. @RajaprabhuAravindasamy wow! I don't know that event. It's useful and dangerous. I still thinking the user needs `blur`

Comment: See image. Second image I want the menu to disappear.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I am not the dvter, But `"focusout" doesn't exist` This might be the cause. And you didn't tell why OP's code was not working

Comment: I explain in comments that I didn't know that event, now I know it, but in this case the OP doesn't needs bubbling, so `blur` is more correct.

Comment: I am (one of) the down voters. And yes, it's because the answer contains false information ("focusout" exists) and is irrelevant (use of focusout  is not the source of the problem being asked about; the missing comma in the selector was the whole issue.)

Comment: @DanielBeck I respect your concern on explaining the reason for downvote.

Comment: Well, doesn't matter. If a code works and solves the OP problem, grow 2 downvotes makes no sense. However I'm used to it in stackoverflow

Comment: The problem is that this removes the suggestion box whenever I click it. Because at the same time the focus is removed from the input box, user_address. I need an `AND` option, where I can see that BOTH elements has lost focus.

Comment: You can't make that with a single listener. But I think that you are wrong in definition. If you show the suggestions when you write something in an input, the blur listener will be sufficient to hide the suggestions even when you make focus in another input, because in the new input you show the suggestions **WHEN YOU WRITE**, not when you focus. However, I don't feel good when I try to help someone and the only thing I see is growing up downvotes and criticism, instead of help in community.

Comment: Agree. I have not downvoted tough, do you know how I can fix this? without having to type in each element on the page that should make it disappear?

Comment: Did you mean this question?: `<div id="another element">Pressing another element on the page should hide the suggestion box</div>` It's very different to focusout/blur.

Comment: That just an example about what I mean about other elements. It's representing 1 of the many other elements on the page.

Comment: Maybe you need to listen onclick and not onblur. Just `$(document).on('click', function(event) { console.log(event.target); });` if target is different to the box suggestions close the box, else don't close nothing!

Comment: This way I have to write up all the other elements. I can already hide the suggestion box whenever I click it. Thats not the problem. But hiding it whenever I write something in the input field, and regret, so I select something else. Thats harder. But I was provided with a working CSS answer. Thank you anyways :)